# Waiting for ajax request to resolve after clicking button

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

```
await page.click('.save');

const value = await page.$eval('.myelement', el => { return el.innerHTML });
```

Clicking the `.save` Button triggers an ajax request that changes `.myelement`s value. How do I wait for that response before I $.eval `.myelement`?

Comment: You can try [`page.waitForResponse()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options).

Comment: that leads to timeout. page.waitFor(2000) is an evil hack but it works.

Comment: Maybe there is a race condition here. See the possible solution in Thomas Dondorf's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`page.waitForNavigation`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) to wait for any network activity to finish when clicking a button like this:

```js
// waits for navigation and clicks promises to resolve
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(), // this promise resolves after navigation has finished
    page.click('.save')
]);

const value = await page.$eval('.myelement', el => { return el.innerHTML });
```

You should not simply use `page.waitForNavigation()` as this might lead to a race condition, when the network activity has already finished before the `page.click` promise is resolved.

#### Alternatives

If that is not working you could also try one of the `waitUntil` options for the function like `networkidle0` or `networkidle2` (e.g. `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })`.

Alternatively, you can use [`page.waitForResponse`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options) instead in case you want to wait for a specific network resource to finish loading or there is constant background traffic (so that waiting for navigation to finish is not an option).